# How should I unit-test digital filters?

Tags: unit-testing, signal-processing, digital-filter

First the question(s):

> How should I write unit tests for a digital filter (band-pass/band-stop) in software? What should I be testing? Is there any sort of *canonical test suite* for filtering?
>
> How to select test inputs, generate expected outputs, and define "conformance" in a way that I can say the actual output *conforms* to expected output?

Now the context:

The application I am developing (electromyographic signal acquisition and analysis) needs to use digital filtering, mostly band-pass and band-stop filtering (C#/.Net in Visual Studio).

The previous version of our application has these filters implemented with some legacy code we could use, but we are not sure how mathematically correct it is, since we don't have unit-tests for them.

Besides that we are also evaluating [Mathnet.Filtering](http://filtering.mathdotnet.com/), but their unit test suite doesn't include subclasses of `OnlineFilter` yet.

We are not sure how to evaluate one filtering library over the other, and the closest we got is to filter some sine waves to eyeball the differences between them. That is not a good approach regarding unit tests either, which is something we would like to automate (instead of running scripts and evaluating the results elsewhere, even visually).

I imagine a good test suite should test something like?

- Linearity and Time-Invariance: how should I write an automated test (with a boolean, "pass or fail" assertion) for that?
- Impulse response: feeding an impulse response to the filter, taking its output, and checking if it "conforms to expected", and in that case:

  - How would I define *expected* response?
  - How would I define *conformance*?
- Amplitude response of sinusoidal input;
- Amplitude response of step / constant-offset input;
- Frequency Response (including Half-Power, Cut-off, Slope, etc.)

I could not be considered an expert in programming or DSP (far from it!) and that's exactly why I am cautious about filters that "seem" to work well. It has been common for us to have clients questioning our filtering algorithms (because they need to publish research where data was captured with our systems), and I would like to have *formal proof* that the filters are working as expected.

DISCLAIMER: [this question was also posted on DSP.StackExchange.com](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/24819/how-to-test-digital-filters)

Comment: some answers at [Verifying DSP functions](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.dsp/tmJGAWhNWZE/fdpV5ZWPt7YJ)

Comment: Before you can create tests, you need to know the requirements for a working or acceptable filter in your particular applications.  Also, the process of a formal proof can be very different from unit testing, depending on the allowed total range of inputs and state.